# What is "Nasdaq Subscriber Agreement"? What's the main content in simple English?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, legal, nasdaq

﻿What is ﻿**Nasdaq Subscriber Agreement**? What's the main content in simple English? The document is loaded with legal terms.

I wish to buy stocks and was forced to sign that document.

Comment: Which "Nasdaq Subscriber Agreement" are you referring to? Nasdaq has lots of subscription products and each one has its own subscriber agreement.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt anybody *forced* you to do anything.

Without knowing the specific agreement you're referring to, I assume you mean the "Nasdaq User Agreement for Real-Time Quotes".

Basically, it lays out the terms and conditions pertaining to its market quotes. These are provided for personal non-professional use and without warranties.

If you can't be bothered to read/skim the document yourself, maybe you're not ready to start trading/investing...